# Listview selected item highlight coming from database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am beginner in android creating religious book I have two activities both have listview the data is coming from sqlite database  when i click any particular item from first activity switch to second activity show  all detail in second activity which also have listview my question how to highlight second list item row only particular item is highlighted ! here example shown in picture what actually i want

[image: picture one verse select]

[image: picture two verse highlight]

here if anyone click on verse 13 all verse 1-25 is  all show but only highlight verse 13 in next activity how   this can be done here is my code

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Chapters extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ListView listView;
        private ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
        private   int booknumber;
        private  String bookname;
        TextView setbookname;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapters);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setbookname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bookname);
            Intent mIntent = getIntent();
             booknumber= mIntent.getIntExtra("booknumber", 0);
             bookname=mIntent.getStringExtra("bookname");


             setbookname.setText(bookname);

            toolbar.setTitle("");
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, ""+booknumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            setData();

            listView =findViewById(R.id.list);

            adapter = new ChapterAdopter(Chapters.this, R.layout.item_listview, stringArrayList);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    int chapternumber=position+1;

                    Toast.makeText(Chapters.this, ""+chapternumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent=new Intent(Chapters.this,Verse.class);

                  intent.putExtra("Booknumber",booknumber);

                  intent.putExtra("Chapternumber",chapternumber);


               startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }



        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // handle arrow click here
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();

            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.chapter,menu);
            MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.chapter_search);

            SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();



            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        private void setData() {



            stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select DISTINCT c from t_asv where b="+booknumber, new String[]{});


            if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do {
                        stringArrayList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }


    }



package bible.swordof.God;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Verse extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private int booknumber;
    private  int chapternumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verse);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
         booknumber = mIntent.getIntExtra("Booknumber", 0);
        chapternumber= mIntent.getIntExtra("Chapternumber", 0);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        setData();

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new VerseAdopter(Verse.this, R.layout.item_listview, stringArrayList);


        Toast.makeText(this, ""+booknumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
          onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chapter, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.chapter_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void setData() {


        stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select  v FROM t_asv where b="+booknumber+" AND c="+chapternumber+";", new String[]{});


        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    stringArrayList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: hey carlos cavero please tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are passing the selected verse as a chapter and then in the query `Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select  v FROM t_asv where b="+booknumber+" AND c="+chapternumber+";", new String[]{});` therefore selecting all verses from the passed book/chapter.

You perhaps need to pass the clicked value as the verse as well as the book and chapter and use a query that includes the verse in the WHERE clause, perhaps `cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select  v FROM t_asv where b="+booknumber+" AND c="+chapternumber+" AND v=" + versenumber + " ;", new String[]{});`

Comment: But mike t how highlight it?

Comment: Something along the lines of `view.setBackgroundColor(the_color_as_an_int)` in the onItemClickListener.

Comment: Mike T may i join you on facebook?

Comment: Hello Mike T how are you if use v=1 its on show speicfic verse